# View Controller Top Bar not editing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

In my `view controller`, I have changed the color of the top bar in the simulated metrics, I have changed it to be 'Translucent Black navigation bar', but when I start up my app in the simulator my top bar is still white.

[image: SCREENSHOT]

Answer (score 1):

Bar`Simulated metrics` only affect how the `NavigationBar`'s overview is displayed in the Interface Builder. The actual `NavigationBar` is either part of your viewController's `navigationController` or a view you added manually.

With `UINavigationcontroller`:

```
self.navigationcontroller.navigation.translucent = false
```

With custom `UINavigationBar`:

```
self.myNavigationBar.translucent = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the NavigationBar tint colour as following screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simulated metrics exist just that you can see what it will look like on launch. It doesn't really affect your app.

If you want to change your navigationBar's color, you must do it programmatically:

**SWIFT**

```
// in ViewController
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.greenColor()
```

**OBJ C**

```
// in ViewController    
self.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```